# ng-click scope properties not updating as expected

Tags: data-binding, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I'm confused as to how angular updates properties on the scope. Here's a contrived version of my code. I expected `$scope.name` to be automatically updated when `$scope.open` changes.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jPpag/2/)

**view**

```html
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-click="click()" ng-controller="MyCtrl">{{name}}</div>
</div>
```

**controller**

```js
var MyCtrl = function ($scope) {
    if (typeof $scope.open === 'undefined') {
        $scope.open = true;
    }

    $scope.name = $scope.open ? "ilia" : "choly";

    $scope.click = function () {
        $scope.open = !$scope.open;
    };
};
```

I can update `$scope.name` in the `click` callback, but I was hoping angular could do that for me.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grs46/1/)

```js
var MyCtrl = function ($scope) {
    if (typeof $scope.open === 'undefined') {
        $scope.open = true;
        $scope.name = "ilia";
    }        

    $scope.click = function () {
        $scope.open = !$scope.open;
        $scope.name = $scope.open ? "ilia" : "choly";
    };
};
```

am I doing something wrong, or is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `name` to be automatically update when `open` changes you can use  [`$watch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope):

> Registers a listener callback to be executed whenever the watchExpression changes.

Like this:

```js
var MyCtrl = function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('open', function () {
        $scope.name = $scope.open ? "ilia" : "choly";
    });

    $scope.open = typeof $scope.open === 'undefined' ? true : $scope.open;

    $scope.click = function () {
        $scope.open = !$scope.open;
    };
};
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hbpYK/